# Compile data from multiple selected Excel files into one Summary file

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a Macro that opens the selected file, searches where the error is occurred and then places it in the Summary file in the active cell.

It was working perfectly but now I had changed it so that i can select multiple files together instead of selecting each file one by one.

Its showing **error in the line `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)` as Typemismatch**

Can someone please help me with that.

```
Sub InputData()

    Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook, temporaryWB As Workbook
    Dim oRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SearchString As String, DateCol As String
    Dim CumSum As Double, counter As Double, cum As Double
    Dim strSheetName As String, CellName As String
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim f As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   ' Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'Set Rng1 = Application.InputBox("select cell where you want to insert new data", Type:=8)

      fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xl*), *.xl*", _
                        Title:="Select File(s) To Be Opened", MultiSelect:=True)

    If IsArray(fNameAndPath) Then
        For f = LBound(fNameAndPath) To UBound(fNameAndPath)
              ' do something with each file as fNameAndPath(f)

    strSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    CellName = ActiveCell.Address
    cum = Range(CellName).Offset(-1, 2).Value


    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set oRange = ws.Range("C:C")

    SearchString = "10000"

    Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)


    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then    ' searching codeID string first time

          '  Set bCell = aCell       ' defining Algorithm to supress repetition
                aCell.Select
                DateCol = aCell.Offset(0, -2)
                counter = aCell.Offset(0, -1)

                wb.Worksheets(strSheetName).Range(CellName) = DateCol
                wb.Worksheets(strSheetName).Range(CellName).Offset(0, 1) = counter


                CumSum = counter + cum
                wb.Worksheets(strSheetName).Range(CellName).Offset(0, 2) = CumSum
                wb.Worksheets(strSheetName).Range(CellName).Offset(0, 3) = "1000000"
                wb.Worksheets(strSheetName).Range(CellName).Offset(0, 4) = "50"


               lastColumn = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
               'If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Offset(1, lastColumn - 2).Value, "1ms", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then

               If InStr(1, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 3).Value, "1ms", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
               wb.Worksheets(strSheetName).Range(CellName).Offset(0, 6) = ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 3)
               wb.Worksheets(strSheetName).Range(CellName).Offset(0, 7) = ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 4)
               ' aCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
               Else

                wb.Worksheets(strSheetName).Range(CellName).Offset(0, 6) = Application.InputBox("Enter error", "Dialog box", ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 3), , , , , 2)
                wb.Worksheets(strSheetName).Range(CellName).Offset(0, 7) = Application.InputBox("Enter error", "Dialog box", ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 4), , , , , 2)
               ' wb.Worksheets(strSheetName).Range(CellName).Offset(0, 6) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, lastColumn - 2)
               End If

    Else
        MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    temporaryWB.Close savechanges:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        Next f
    Else
        'no files selected
    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *fNameAndPath* variable is an array and you are indexing through it with *f*. You need to add the index to the array so that Workbooks.Open knows which piece to pull out of the array.

```
 Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath(f))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer its working ok but now its showing an error in line   wb.Worksheets(strSheetName).Range(CellName) = DateCol as script out of Range.

Comment: When you debug the code, what are the values for *strSheetName* and *CellName* and do they exist? That error is typical of trying to access something that is named wrong, referenced wrong or simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Most likey, `strSheetName` does not exist in `wb` (=`Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)`).